# How i can display three Div and one form to be just below each other

Tags: html, css, razor

I have the following markup inside razor view, at the top navigation bar of my web site:-

```
<section id="login" class="navbar-search pull-right">
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {  <span class="username customTopNavText " style=" display:block; ">

[<a href="~/Account/LogOff/" style="color:white"> Logout </a> ]                                
                                                                                              <i class="icon-user"></i> <strong >  @User.Identity.Name.Substring(User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\\") + 1) </strong></span>


<div  class="customTopNavText" id="currentdate"></div>
<div  class="customTopNavText" id="currenttime" ></div> 
 <form class="customSearch"method="GET" action="@Url.Action("Search", "Home")">

<input name="exactmatch" type="hidden" value="true">    <b>Search by Tag </b>   <input  class="push-up-button searchmargin" placeholder="Search by tag.." name="searchTerm2" data-autocomplete-source= "@Url.Action("AutoComplete", "Home")" type="text" style=" width:150px; margin-top:8px"/><input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn" />

  </form>
<br/>  <a href="~/Home/AdvanceSearch/" style="color:white;font-size:11px;float:right;border-width:0px"> Advance Search </a>
 }</section>
```

what i am trying to achieve is to have the "Advance Search link just below the search button, currently i am getting these output on IE:-

[image]

and on firefox:-

[image]

can anyone advice how i can force the advance search link to be just below the search button?

Thanks

Comment: Try getting rid of the <br/> and clearing the float on advanced search

Comment: @WombleGold i already tried this but it will not fix this..

Answer (score 0):

In order to push Advance Search link just below the search button, inline style can be used like this i.e:

```
<a href="~/Home/AdvanceSearch/" style="color:white; font-size:11px; position:absolute; top:30px; left:200px;"> Advance Search </a>
```

you can set the top and left according to the setting that fits to you. give multiple values to top and left and choose the best which fits to the area in which you wants.

Here,

```
position:relative    // make position of your <a></a> absolute
top:30px;            // place your <a></a> to 30px down from top of your parent div or element
left:200px;          // place your <a></a> to a distance of 200px far from left border of your div or element
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but i think setting this link to be absolute is not recommended because users will be accessing the system using different resolutions ,, and having fix top & left only for this link will work on some screens while on others the "advance search" link will be positioned maybe above the search button , and i will have overlaps in the DOM...becuase currenlty the serach textbox and search button in addtion to the date and time are not set to be obsolute..

Comment: Absolute positioning is relative to the first parent element that is set to `position: relative;` If it doesn't encounter one, it positions it based on the body/window/page size. So this answer is half-true, you should first wrap the element (or set an existing element) to relative positioning, i don't see one in your code.

Comment: @Pim you are saying right about positioning, its my mistake in code but my mean is same as you said. I edited it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to set `margin-top` to a sufficient height on Advance search. If it isn't "blocked" by the search input field, it will float to the right of the page, leaving you to just set the margin height.

Comment: setting margin-top or margin-left or margin-right will not have any effect not sure why, seems the link is trapped by other components,, any idea about this ?

Comment: Could you put this in a workable fiddle or something so I can take a look at it more easily?

Answer (score -1):

I would use a table inside the div/container to layout exactly where to put it. The container would hve the positioning applied to it and then the advanced search will always be in the same place as the search bar. all you would need to do is format the table and every browser you open, all the elements will be in the same place.

for example:

```
<form ...... >
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="~/Home/AdvanceSearch/" style="color:white;font-size:11px;float:right;border-width:0px"> Advance Search </a></td>
    <td><b>Search by Tag </b></td>
    <td><input  class="push-up-button searchmargin" placeholder="Search by tag.." name="searchTerm2" data-autocomplete-source= "@Url.Action("AutoComplete", "Home")" type="text" style=" width:150px; margin-top:8px"/></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: this will have a wrong style, and i could use this , but as best practice in managing web sites layouts , is to avoid using tables for layouts..